# Does a public use aircraft need an aircraft registration hard card?

Tags: aircraft-registration

Does an aircraft, operating public use, need a aircraft registration hard card?

Comment: What jurisdiction are you asking about? FAA?

Comment: What _is_ an "aircraft registration hard card"?

Comment: @FreeMan Google suggests its an FAA Form 8050-3.

Comment: If you are talking about the FAA and if you are talking about a physical registration card (certificate), then yes, as per [FAR 91.203](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.203) a physical copy of the certificate is required on board the aircraft.

Comment: @RonBeyer Doesn't §91.203 apply to civil aircraft, not public aircraft?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/31659/62)